# Trapezoid Rule - Number of Points

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

How many points should we use in the trapezoid rule in computing an approximate value of $\int_{0}^{1} e^{x^2} dx$ if the answer is to be within $10^{-6}$ of the correct value?

I'm looking at the basic trapezoid rule and I don't see anywhere in the formula where it takes in different number of points.

Comment: Do you know the error bound for the trapezoid rule?

Comment: How many points we should use is a complicated question. The upper bound we get by finding the max of the second derivative in the interval is often unduly pessimistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You know that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) the error is lower than
$$
\sup_{[0,1]}|f''| /12n^2
$$with $n$ points. Now just compute the derivative.

You find that $\sup_{[0,1]}|f''| = \sup_{[0,1]} (2+4x^2)e^{x^2}=6e$ and then
$$
\sup_{[0,1]}|f''| /12n^2 < \epsilon \iff n > \sqrt\frac e{2\epsilon}\simeq 10^3
$$

Comment: But...we have to find an $n$ from the error bound formula s.t. we get an error less than $10^{-6}$ right? So instead of the epsilon, shouldn't we have written $10^{-6}$ so we can find an error less than that?

Comment: yes, here $\epsilon = 10^{-6}$

Comment: So then I get http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28e%2F%282+*+10%5E%28-6%29%29%29 right? ~1165.82 which is...a  large number. So... $n > 1165.82$ is the answer??

Comment: exactly. If you take such a value you are sure of the correctness of the integration up to 1e-6

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help! This was a lot easier than expected